# How do we increase the region of convergence for the Riemann Zeta function (using Dirichlet Series form)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

The Riemann Zeta Function can be defined as: $\zeta(s)=\sum \frac 1 {n^s}$ for $s>1$. The series converges for $s>1$. wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) mentions that:

An extension of the area of convergence can be obtained by rearranging the original series.

(1) The series $\zeta (s)={\frac {1}{s-1}}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left({\frac {n}{(n+1)^{s}}}-{\frac {n-s}{n^{s}}}\right)$
converges for $Re(s) > 0$

(2) while $\zeta (s)={\frac {1}{s-1}}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {n(n+1)}{2}}\left({\frac {2n+3+s}{(n+1)^{s+2}}}-{\frac {2n-1-s}{n^{s+2}}}\right)$ converges even for $Re(s) > −1$.
In this way, the area of convergence can be extended to Re(s) > −k for any negative integer $−k$.

**Query 1:** I am very new to analysis so can someone please explain this series rearrangement process for a layman?

**Query 2:** Using (1) I tried to extract the real and imaginary parts of the $\zeta (s)$ as:

$Re(\zeta (s))={\frac {1}{s-1}}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac {n(C_{n+1})}{(n+1)^{b}}} - {\frac {(n-b)C_n}{n^{b}}}+{\frac {cS_n}{n^{b}}}$

$Img(\zeta (s))={\frac {i}{s-1}}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}-{\frac {n(S_{n+1})}{(n+1)^{b}}} + {\frac {(n-b)S_n}{n^{b}}}+{\frac {cC_n}{n^{b}}}$

where $C_{n}= \cos(c \ln(n)), S_{n}= \sin(c \ln(n)), C_{n+1}= \cos(c \ln(n+1)), S_{n+1}= \sin(c \ln(n+1))$ and $[s=b+ic]$.

I am unsure if these are correct (i.e. these converge for $Re(s)>0$). Can someone please clarify what is incorrect here?

Comment: I don't know about rearrangement, but the zeta function can be extended via the Euler-Maclaurin formula, which uses the series expansion mainly, without reference to Gamma functions or other things.

Comment: I am particularly interested in specifically how the above two series were arrived at and what is the general process. Moreover most of the other extensions depend on quiet complicated functions (which for laymen like me seem too much)

Comment: With respect to Query 1, the Wikipedia article references Knopp, Konrad (1947). [Theory of Functions, Part Two](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.212186/page/n55/mode/2up). New York, Dover publications. pp. [51–55](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.212186/page/n57/mode/2up) which perhaps provides the derivation.

Comment: @StevenClark I saw that. As I mentioned I am just beginning so I didn't get at all. I hoped since this Zeta is such a well studied function someone i might be able to get some help ere